# How to disable .select2() javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following bulk of code:

```
    $(function() {
    $('#dataSource').select2({ multiple: true, data: @Html.Raw(Model.AvailableDataSources) });

    $("#dataSource").bind("change", function() { 
        if ($("#dataSource").val().length <= 0) {
            //Disable the select2()
        }
    });
});
```

I need to disable the .select2 field if there are no data souces. How can I disable it ?

Comment: Did you try `$("#dataSource")[0].disabled = true`?

Comment: @Philicare I didn't put '[0]' before, now it is working. But what if I have data sources and I still want to disable all of them ? Should I do this in a loop and disable all of them individually ?

Comment: You could use `$('#dataSource').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`.

Comment: You should just be able to use `$('#dataSource').select2('enable',false)`

Comment: @AdrianChiritescu, I added a solution for several fields in my answer.

Comment: @Philicare its perfect, that's all I needed, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, @AdrianChiritescu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete working sample:

To disable only one field:

```js
$("#dataSource").change(function(){
  if (!$("#dataSource").val())
  {
    $(this)[0].disabled = true ;
  }
})

function enableDataSource()
{ $("#dataSource")[0].disabled = false ;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="dataSource" value="" />
<button onclick="enableDataSource()">Enable field</button>
```

To disable several fields by class name:

```js
$(".dataSource").change(function(){
  if (!$(this).val())
  {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true) ;
  }
})

function enableDataSource()
{ $(".dataSource").attr('disabled', false);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="dataSource" value="" />
<input type="text" class="dataSource" value="" />    <input type="text" class="dataSource" value="" />    <button onclick="enableDataSource()">Enable field</button>
```